Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.time
I was running a Java code in Windows which was working fine, but when I moved it to Linux (fedora), I started getting the Prohibited package name error.
To check if it was due to my code, I took a small example of DateTimeFormatter, but the problem remains.

I have moved the code to a basic /home/try folder
Updated Java

Note: I have seen a few similar queries here, but in those cases package keyword was used with java/java.lang. That isn't the case for me
This is the code
import java.time.LocalDateTime; // Import the LocalDateTime class
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; // Import the DateTimeFormatter class

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Before formatting: " + myDateObj);
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    String formattedDate = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);
    System.out.println("After formatting: " + formattedDate);
  }
}

And this is the result

[root@surface-01 try]# java  -cp ":/usr/java/jre1.8.0_411/lib/rt.jar" Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.time

Can any one please help me figuring this out?

Which java version do you use?

I think the version may be the issue. checking now on latest version.

Hello Asheessh, welcome, your code is ok, only change the name of package, this cant not be "java.time".

Setting java runtime environment and removing rt.jar from the command line  should fix your problem.

Does the command java Main work?


java -cp ":/usr/java/jre1.8.0_411/lib/rt.jar"

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish by shoving the boot classpath of a JRE1.8 onto your classpath, but this is the source of your problem, and you cannot fix it.
The issue is, that you're telling java to treat rt.jar as a dependency same as any other. However, starting with JDK17 or so, you cannot do that - only bootclasspath entries can declare anything in the java.* package. Everything in rt.jar is in the java.* package, pretty much. Hence, you can't do that, and you can't tell JDK17 to allow it anyway. Before JDK17 this was allowed just fine, and that explains why your code 'works on windows but not on linux' - it's not about windows or linux. It's that on your windows machine you are trying this with an older java and on the linux box, with a newer one. If you upgade the JDK on windows, it'll break there; if you downgrade your JDK on linux, it'll start working there.
java.time is irrelevant here - it just so happens to be the first thing that is being loaded, somehow, not from bootclasspath (which takes priority) but from that jar; loading anything from that rt.jar would cause this issue. That -cp option either does nothing (in which case, remove it), or it causes this error. It cannot possibly do anything useful.
But don't downgrade your JDK - that way lies insecurity. No, fix the problem. What are you trying to do with including the java 1.8 RT.jar?

I wrote this targeting JDK1.8

It is likely that it'll just run on newer versions. Java has broken a bunch of things especially in the 8-to-9 transition, but what it broke has little to do with the runtime classpath. Just.. remove the -cp "rt.jar" part entirely and try again.

I tried again and I get some error about missing java.xml or javax.Generated or javafx or some such.

Search the web - these are well known problems with well known solutions, and 'shove the entire JRE8 rootcp onto the classpath of a more modern JVM' never was a good solution, and now doesn't work at all.

I don't know why I did that

Then.. don't.

It really can only run on JDK1.8. I know this / have been told.

Then there's nothing for it but to get an actual JDK1.8. Fortunately, you can install many java versions side by side, no problems. Note that it's hard to find a JDK1.8 that is still actively supported, and running unsupported JVMs is a potential security issue.

I want to ensure it runs on JDK1.8; I have more modern ones but I intend to deploy it on machines with over-a-decade-old JDK installations.

See previous point - you can't do that reliably without having an actual JDK1.8 and running it on there. Note that most Java IDEs have an option to target a specific version and to pick a specific JVM to compile and run with. Use those options so your IDE tells you when you use things that wouldn't work on JDK1.8.

Some other reason

Edit your answer.
